# calculate internet download, upload speed in electronjs, nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, electron

I have to test users' upload and download speeds outside local servers as in speedtest.net

The best option was to try to download an image from a server, and calculate the speed according to the time period

```js
 const imageAddr =
    'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1676439977216-912b62fadb7e?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=6000&q=100';
 const downloadSize = 10000000;
```

```js
      export async function internetCheck(downloadSize: number, imageAddr: string) {
          return new Promise<string>((resolve, reject) => {
            try {
              let endTime: number;
              const startTime = new Date().getTime();
              const cacheBuster = `?nnn= ${startTime}`;
              const download = new Image();
              download.src = imageAddr + cacheBuster;
              download.onload = async () => {
                endTime = new Date().getTime();
                const duration = (endTime - startTime) / 1000;
                const bitsLoaded = downloadSize * 8;
                const speedBps: any = (bitsLoaded / duration).toFixed(2);
                const speedKbps: any = (speedBps / 1024).toFixed(2);
                const speedMbps = (speedKbps / 1024).toFixed(2);
                console.log('Utils', speedMbps);
        
                resolve(speedMbps);
              };
            } catch (e) {
              reject(e);
            }
          });
        }
```

But this was not accurate enough

Is there any accurate way to calculate this

Comment: How is this inaccurate?

Comment: @James The size of the image above is 9.5 MB -> Give these numbers  `speedMbps =  2541.96
` `speedKbps =  2602961.98`

Comment: Oh - the cache buster part probably isn’t working since the image url already has a `?`.  If that’s always the case you could try changing the `?` to `&` in the `const cachebuster` line.

Comment: @James nice catch james, But there is something I didn't understand. Now I get results between 7 and 8 without throttling, I think my internet is over 30. Can I rely on these results

Comment: You're only measuring the speed between the client and images.unsplash.com, obviously.  This isn't necessarily the same as speed between the client and some other server.